# Trouble using grunt connect server on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, gruntjs

All the tutorials I can find use some kind of app.js to run their node server on heroku.

I have already configured my grunt - connect task to use modRewrite for my single page app so that all requests simply return index.html. So it would be convenient for me to somehow just have heroku run my `grunt dist` once it npm installs.

I have tried adding this line to my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "echo postinstall time; ./node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js dist"
  }
```

But I think there is something wrong with my path, because it doesn't work. I get a Permission denied error.

I also tried using a simple app.js express server (even though I would have to re-figure out how to do the modRewrite) -- but that failed somewhere along the line - heroku was looking for an index.js, which I don't have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is a simple connect server using the same modRewrite code from my grunt task:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');

var app = connect()
  .use(modRewrite(
    ['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']
  ))
  .use(connect.static('./dist/'))
  .listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

And the following Procfile:

```
web: node app.js
```